# Expandable Groups in Windows Forms ListView control

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How do you make the item groups in a Windows Forms ListView control collapsible and expandable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a working answer here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ListViewGroupCollapsible.aspx